# Passing data into html from Java via Spring

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to pass a String value from my Spring controller class to my HTML? In various "hello world" examples, they say to use

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("htmlPageName");
model.addAttribute("variableName", "someValue");
```

in the controller and

```
${variableName}
```

in the HTML. But when I load the page it shows literally `${variableName}` instead of `"someValue"`

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need a renderer like JSP or thymeleaf

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but I think I tried using thymeleaf. I added "xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"" to the html tag and tried making a label with "th:text="..."" to test, but it did the same thing. Do I also need a maven dependency? I can't find any (useful) tutorials or examples

Comment: post your current pom/ project structure.

Comment: ${variableName} use like this

Comment: Put your html code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use Thymeleaf

```
<h1 th:text="${variableName}"></h1>
```

You wrote: {$variableName} instead of ${variableName}

Comment: what if this variable contains "<br/>" tag? Something like "hello <br/> world", but this does not work. hello world is showing in the same line instead of different lines

Answer (score 1):

You can find thymeleaf [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) in here that show how to show model attribute in html.

In Thymeleaf, these model attributes (or context variables in Thymeleaf jargon) can be accessed with the following syntax: `${attributeName}`, where attributeName in our case is messages.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView messages() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("message/list");
        mav.addObject("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
        return mav;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The reason I came to StackOverflow is because that documentation was unhelpful. They don't explain it very well. I don't know what I'm missing, it looks like it should be working

Comment: Did you change your variable ${attributeName} like that ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it by itself, I tried it with and without quotes, and I tried it as label text as th:text

Comment: Then I think problem is not here. Your thymeleaf does not work maybe.

Comment: Could you add your config file also ?